# How can i use svg to change page and post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm try to use svg and make shape can redirect to next page by ajax.
when page was redirect also post data to next page.
but i don't know how to do.
here is my code i have try:

HTML:

```
<circle fill="red" cx="100" cy="100" onclick=NodesDown(5)>
```

Javascript:

```
function NodesDown(id) {
  //
  $.ajax({
    url:'index_view.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: {grade: id}
  })
  .done(function() {
    location.href="index_view.php";
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });

}
```

index_view.php

```
<?php echo $_POST[grade]; ?>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, or what the issue is. Could you provide some more information.

Comment: Redirect by ajax is nonsence. You either send ajax and stay on current page (and must display the content with JS) or do a redirect and load a next page. For a redirect with POST data see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm use this way to resolve my question.
js:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'php/data_nodes_PDO_test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {indicator: newURL[1]}
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('.backToPage').css('display', 'inline');
    $("#root > g > g").remove();
    $("#root > g > line").remove();
    $("#root > g > marker").remove();


    console.log("success" + data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });
```

console:

```
[{"id":"6","map_id":null,"Nodes_text":"(5-n-11-S01)","transform":"translate(-468,-619)","class":"sNodes","r":"15","source":null,"target":null,"fixed":null,"indicator":"5-n-11-S01"},{"id":"7","map_id":null,"Nodes_text":"(5-b-01)","transform":"translate(513,615)","class":"bNodes","r":"25","source":null,"target":null,"fixed":null,"indicator":"5-b-01"},false,false,false]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a page while sending POST data, the easiest way is to create a form and submit it.

```
$('<form>')
    //create input for each value you want to send
    .append($('<input>').attr('name', 'grade').val(id))
    //define how and where to the data will be send
    .attr('method', 'POST')
    .attr('action', 'index_view.php')
    .submit()
;
```

*Just an example, not actually tested. You may need to add more properties to correctly submit it (maybe you will need submit button inside the form as well?).*

Answer (score 0):

To replace current page with a HTML loaded via AJAX, you need to use document.write() method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index_view.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {grade: id}
}).always(function(response, status) {
    if ('success' !== status) {
        alert('Cannot download');
        return;
    }

    document.open('text/html','replace');
    document.write(response);
    document.close();
});
```

In some browsers (specifically Chrome), this may break History object and functionality of Back, Forward and Reload!